# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted when login to admin mezzanine

Tags: python, django, web, mezzanine

I deploy project web into server but when i login admin page it has an error

`Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

It's normal when I test in local.

My project used mezzanine CMS and i use default login of mezzanine.

Thanks you very much , i fixed it

Comment: if it works on localhost but not on server, perhaps it is related to your configuration. read the official doc may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/

Comment: i have read it but still have no more information about it.

Comment: Django app for handling the server headers required for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Comment: thanks you very much i already fixed it..just change in gunicorn setting file